# Continuous quantiles of a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile, quartile

I have a data set, for which I graphed a regression (using `ggplot2`'s `stat_smooth`) :

```
ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x=time, y=pdm)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(col="red")
```

[image: plot1]

I'd also like to have the quantiles (if it's simpler, having only the quartiles will do) using the same method. All I manage to get is the following :

```
ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x=time, y=pdm, z=surface)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(col="red") + stat_quantile(quantiles = c(0.25,0.75))
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't put `method="loess"` in `stat_quantile()`, which, if I'm not mistaken, would solve my problem.

(In case it's not clear, desired behavior = non linear regressions for the quantiles, and therefore the regression for Q25 and Q75 being below and above (respectively) my red curve (and Q50, if plotted, would be my red curve)).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`stat_quantile` is, by default, plotting best-fit lines for the 25th and 75th percentiles at each x-value. `stat_quantile` uses the `rq` function from the `quantreg` package (implicitly, `method="rq"` in the `stat_quantile` call). As far as I know, `rq` doesn't do loess regression. However, you can use other flexible functions for the quantile regression. Here are two examples:

B-Spline:

```
library(splines)

stat_quantile(formula=y ~ bs(x, df=4), quantiles = c(0.25,0.75))
```

Second-Order Polynomial:

```
stat_quantile(formula=y ~ poly(x, 2), quantiles = c(0.25,0.75))
```

`stat_quantile` is still using `rq`, but `rq` accepts formulas of the type listed above (if you don't supply a formula, then `stat_quantile` is implicitly using `formula=y~x`). If you use the same formula in `geom_smooth` as for `stat_quantile`, you'll have consistent regression methods being used for the quantiles and for the mean expectation.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Isn't it possible to put `loess()` from `stats` in the `formula` arg ?

Comment: (I'm trying to use `loess`, with this : `stat_quantile(formula = loess(mydf$pdm ~ mydf$time), quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))`, and I get this error : `Warning messages:`  
`1: 'newdata' had 100 rows but variables found have 6816 rows`  

`2: Computation failed in 'stat_quantile()':`  
`replacement has 6816 rows, data has 100  `, I have no idea what it's trying to tell me.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `loess` to work in `stat_quantile`. 'stat_quantile` uses the `rq` function from the `quantreg` package. `rq` handles formulas with polynomials and splines (as in my answer), but doesn't do `loess` regression (as far as I can tell). A note on syntax: *If* the `loess` function could do quantile regression, the call would be something like this: `stat_quantile(method="loess", quantiles=c(0.25,0.75))` (which also implicitly uses `formula=y~x`).

Comment: Yes, I tried it too, to no avail. Thank you for trying though. Even though I'm not sure it is exactly what I wanted, I ended up doing what's in here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-October/291575.html, which is putting the quantiles in the DF, and plotting `stat_smooth()` on each one : `ggplot(data = qdfm, aes(x=time, y=pdm)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(col="red") + stat_smooth(data = qdfm, aes(x = time, y = Q25))  + stat_smooth(data = qdfm, aes(x = time, y = Q75))`