# "Replacement has n rows, data has p" error message with loess()

Tags: r, loess

This question is related [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315152/continuous-quantiles-of-a-scatterplot#comment60283983_36315595).

I'm trying to use `loess()` inside `ggplot2`'s `stat_smooth()`, this way :

```
ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x=time, y=pdm, z=surface))
    + geom_point() + stat_smooth(col="red") 
    + stat_quantile(formula = loess(mydf$pdm ~ mydf$time), quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

However, I get the following error message :

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: 'newdata' had 100 rows but variables found have 6816 rows
>
> 2: Computation failed in 'stat_quantile()':
>
> replacement has 6816 rows, data has 100

Any idea of what is going on / how to get it to work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`stat_quantile` doesn't support this. `formula` should be a formula object, which is then passed to the method. If you need Additive Quantile Regression Smoothing use `method = "rqss"`. If you want to use `stat_smooth` actually use `stat_smooth`. However, the `formula` will still expect a formula object, but you can use `loess` as a method there.